# Rownum between clause not working - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I have a table:

table1

```
user_id
1
2
3
4
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT 
rownum, user_id
FROM 
table1 where rownum between 1 and 4;
```

But when I run, it does not work:

```
SELECT 
rownum, user_id
FROM 
table1 where rownum between 2 and 4;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kaushik Nayak I don't think this is a duplication of the referenced one.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : I added another one  which is almost exactly same.

Comment: @KaushikNayak exactly, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rownum` is incremented as the result set is generated.  If the value "1" is never generated, then "2" is never generated.

Because you want to return the row number, I would recommend using `row_number()`:

```
select seqnum, user_id
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum between 2 and 4;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the order of the result set.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So your original query is functionally equivalent to:

```
select (1 + rownum), userid
from table1
where rownum <= 3;
```

Because the ordering is not specified.  With a specified ordering, you can use `row_number()`.

In Oracle 12C+, you can also express this as:

```
select rownum, userid
from table1
offset 1 row fetch first 3 rows only;
```

Comment: If I don't specify order by, would Oracle give me different results?

Comment: @dang . . . If you don't specify the `order by`, then the ordering of the rows in the result set is indeterminate and can differ from run to run.

Answer (score 1):

The first row to return has number 1.
This doesn't match the criterion so it will not be returned.
The same criterion applies for each row.
Therefore, no rows will be returned.